# Eager load a self-referencing table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, hierarchical-data

I have a standard self referencing table of `Categories`. In my entity model I have made associations `Children` and `Parent`. Is it possible to load the whole `Category` object without lazy loading?

if I use the code below, it loads only to the second level.

```
db.Categories.MergeOption = System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.NoTracking;

var query = from c in db.Categories.Include("Children")
            where c.IsVisible == true
            orderby c.SortOrder, c.Id
            select c;
```

Is it possible to load references if I have all the category objects already loaded?

One method to load it is to add the `Children` property multiple times

```
db.Categories.Include("Children.Children.Children.Children.Children")
```

but this generates a very long insane T-SQL code and also it doesn't do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't possible. Consider: All LINQ to Entities queries are translated into SQL. Which SQL statement includes an unlimited depth in a self-referencing hierarchy? In standard SQL, there isn't one. If there's an extension for this in T-SQL, I don't know what it is, and I don't think EF providers do, either.

Comment: But if i run query "SELECT * FROM Categories" i have loaded whole table and also i have loaded all parent and children categories, because they're all in one table. So in this case it isn't very complicated to assign this loaded records to referenced properties, or not?

Comment: If you actually iterated the entire table, then all the objects *would* be in memory and *would* already be fixed up, with or without Include. But that won't happen until you have reached the last record in the table. Include guarantees that the related objects will be there on the *first* record you iterate.

Comment: "Which SQL statement includes an unlimited depth in a self-referencing hierarchy?" -> Common Table Expressions in T-SQL

Comment: He didn't ask for it in one query. But I guess that's what he's looking for based on a comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you might consider using Load method.

```
 if (!category.Children.IsLoaded)
        category.Children.Load();
```

Of course, category entity need to be tracked by ObjectContext.

There is better explanation here [how-does-entity-framework-work-with-recursive-hierarchies-include-seems-not-to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308158/how-does-entity-framework-work-with-recursive-hierarchies-include-seems-not-to).

Comment: I know this method (it will generate hundrets of T-SQL queries), but also i muss load it without tracking, because i'm saving it into cache. I'm looking for something else. If i load whole table of categories, i have loaded also parents and children categories, but the association properties are not loaded. Also i have related table of CategoryType and i muss load it for each category regardless of they referenced the same row...

Comment: Ok, i didn't see that you have to cache it. Hmm, I'll try to think how this could be solved.

Answer (score 0):

One way I have used to implement that if I have several entities I want to get all children in self-referencing table is to use **recursive cte** and **stored procedure** to get their ids using Entity FrameWork :
[Here is the code using Entity Framework and code first approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48870595/8618595)