# walking list using cte

Tags: sqlite, common-table-expression

Still learning SQL :)
This time I'd like to a 'linked list' walk from a table I guess using CTE.
Despite all the example on the web I could not find one simple example I could start from then peek and poke from there.

Here is my table

```
create table yo (id integer, nx integer)
select * from yo
id          nx
----------  ----------
1           5
2           4
3           7
4           9
5           3
6           0
7           0
8           6
9           8
```

I'd like to get a list of 'id','nx' from yo  following the next link 'nx' given a start 'id'

So a start 'id' of 1 would produce

```
id          nx
----------  ----------
1           5
3           7
5           3
7           0
```

Note that 0 is a end marker.

I can't find the magic SQL for doing this
Thanx in advance
Cheers,
Phi

Comment: My table is garbled in my initial question dunno ho w to edit my inial post

Comment: This is the same as the typical parent/child relationship. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Fixed my table display in main question (sorry about that). CL there is no problem, (I think) but it is me beiin a beginner, I tried to 'duplicate' example given on the net, but there are too complicate and I can't make it works. I mean I am not able to craft the SQL statement to obtain a list of (id,nx) starting at some point in the chain.

Comment: Ha the search keyword here is parent/child, I keep searching for 'list' I found a stackoverflow response will look if it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914472/cte-to-get-all-children-descendants-of-a-parent

Answer (score 2):

The first row of the list is easy:

```
SELECT id, nx
FROM yo
WHERE id = 1
```

If the `nx` column of the previous entry is available as `list.nx`, the next entry can be returned with this query:

```
SELECT yo.id, yo.nx
FROM yo
JOIN list ON yo.id = list.nx
```

Then just plug these together:

```
WITH RECURSIVE list(id, nx) AS (
  SELECT id, nx
  FROM yo
  WHERE id = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT yo.id, yo.nx
  FROM yo
  JOIN list ON yo.id = list.nx
)
SELECT * FROM list
```

(This stops automatically because there is no row where `id` is zero; otherwise, you could add a `WHERE list.nx != 0`.)

Comment: Thanx CL, I was almost there schoking on the join. It runs like a champs, and I can handle circular list as well with the WHERE list.nx!=1 (assuming orignal chanded to have entry 7 pointing back to 1 instead of beiing 0. Again thanx.

Comment: A better way to prevent an endless loop is using UNION instead of UNION ALL (see the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html)).