# T-SQL / SQL Server - How to recursively select all nested children IDs of a given parent?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following table and hierarchy:

[image]

How can I select all children ids `(10012, 10013, 10014)` if I have id of parent `10011` (elegantly and efficiently)?

Here `ParentId` self references a parent folder.

Comment: recursive CTE...

Comment: Here's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914472/cte-to-get-all-children-descendants-of-a-parent

Answer (score 2):

Use a recursive [cte](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
;WITH cte 
AS
(   SELECT
        b.FolderId, b.FolderName, b.ParentiD
    FROM
        table b
    WHERE
        FolderId= 10011
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        e.FolderId, e.FolderName, e.ParentId
    FROM
        table  e
    INNER JOIN
        cte r ON e.ParentId = r.FodlerId
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [FolderID] INT
   ,[FolderName] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[ParentID] INT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([FolderID], [FolderName], [ParentID])
VALUES (10011, 'NEw Folder', NULL)
      ,(10012, 'NEw Folder', 10011)
      ,(10013, 'NEw Folder', 10012)
      ,(10014, 'NEw Folder', 10013)
      ,(10021, 'NEw Folder', NULL)
      ,(10022, 'NEw Folder', 10021)
      ,(10023, 'NEw Folder', 10022);

DECLARE @ParentID INT = 10011;

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM @DataSource
    WHERE [FolderID] = @ParentID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A.*
    FROM DataSource R
    INNER JOIN @DataSource A
        ON R.[FolderID] = A.[ParentID]
)     
SELECT DISTINCT [FolderID]
FROM DataSource
WHERE [FolderID] <> @ParentID;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

simple self-join will help you

```
select e.folderid from table1 e inner join table1 t on e.parentid = t.folderid where t.parentid = 10011
```

try the above query :)