# Need help to construct the query from parent-child structure table

Tags: sql

I need to construct the query or function to solve my data structure problem.

My data struture only keep the parent node not the child node. Here the sample.

```
                        ┌───────┐            ┌───────┐
Level-1                 │   A   │            │   B   │          ────────► node is Unlimited
                        └───┬───┘            └───┬───┘
                            │                    │
                      ┌─────┴─────┐         ┌────┴──────┐
                      │           │         │           │
                      │           │         │           │
                ┌─────┴─┐     ┌───┴───┐ ┌───┴───┐    ┌──┴────┐
Level-2         │  C1   │     │  EE   │ │  EF   │    │  G1   │  ────────► node is Unlimited
                └───┬───┘     └───────┘ └───┬───┘    └───┬───┘
                    │                       │            │
         ┌──────────┴────────┐              │         ┌──┴─────────┐
Level-3  │                   │              │         │            │
      ┌──┴────┐          ┌───┴───┐      ┌───┴───┐   ┌─┴─────┐  ┌───┴───┐
      │  HH   │          │   IU  │      │  JK   │   │  JA   │  │  JJ   │ ──► node is Unlimited
      └───────┘          └───────┘      └───────┘   └───────┘  └───────┘
         │                                              │     
Level-4  │                                              │     
      ┌──┴────┐                                     ┌───┴───┐
      │  OT   │                  │                  │  PT   │ ──► node is Unlimited
      └───────┘                  │                  └───────┘
                                 ▼
                    
                     Deep of level is unlimited
```

---

```
Table Node

+------+------+-------------+
| Rec# | Node | Parent_Node |
+------+------+-------------+
|  1   |  A   |             |
|  2   |  B   |             |
|  3   |  C1  |     A       |
|  4   |  EE  |     A       |
|  5   |  EF  |     B       |
|  6   |  G1  |     B       |
|  7   |  HH  |     C1      |
|  8   |  IU  |     C1      |
|  9   |  JK  |     EF      |
|  10  |  JA  |     G1      |
|  11  |  JJ  |     G1      |
|  12  |  OT  |     HH      |
|  13  |  PT  |     JA      |
+------+------+-------------+
```

---

The question is how to build query or function for retrieving data from this structure ?,.

1. For getting all data below the level. 
    Example : 
   from node A (level-1) => { the result should be: C1,EE,HH,IU,OT } 
   from node C1 (level-2) => { the result should be: HH,IU,OT }
2. For getting just 1 level down, or several down of level. 
    Example :  
    Get 1 Level down, from node B (level-1) => { the result should be: EF and G1 Only} 
   Get 2 level down, from node G1 (level-2) => { the result should be: JA, JJ and PT }


   Thank You.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server; what RDBMS are you *really* using? What have **you** tried to solve your problem? Why didn't it work?

Comment: use recursive cte

Comment: Both MySQL and SQL Server support  recursive cte.

Comment: Hi, can you explain more about recursive, I am newbie, and know several query statement .

Comment: can you give me a guide ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914472/cte-to-get-all-children-descendants-of-a-parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an recursive CTE for your query. I haven't finished the formatting but it gives you the recursive CTE.
You haven't specified your RBMS, this is in SQL server. See dbFiddle link at the bottom.

> ```
> create table nodes(
> Rec int,
> Node varchar(5),
> Parent_Node varchar(5));
> ```

> ```
> insert into nodes values
> (1,'A',null),
> (2,'B',null),
> (3,'C1','A'),
> (4,'EE','A'),
> (5,'EF','B'),
> (6,'G1','B'),
> (7,'HH','C1'),
> (8,'IU','C1'),
> (9,'JK','EF'),
> (10,'JA','G1'),
> (11,'JJ','G1'),
> (12,'OT','HH'),
> (13,'PT','JA');
> ```

> ```
> with noder as 
> ( 
> select  
>   Parent_Node n1, 
>   Node n2, 
>   cast(null as varchar(5)) n3, 
>   cast(null as varchar(5)) n4, 
>   cast(null as varchar(5)) n5
> from nodes
>   union all 
> select 
>   Parent_node,n1,n2,n3,n4
> from nodes
> join noder on n1 = Node 
> )
> select *
> from Noder 
> where n1 is not null
> ```

> ```
> n1 | n2 | n3   | n4   | n5  
> :- | :- | :--- | :--- | :---
> A  | C1 | null | null | null
> A  | EE | null | null | null
> B  | EF | null | null | null
> B  | G1 | null | null | null
> C1 | HH | null | null | null
> C1 | IU | null | null | null
> EF | JK | null | null | null
> G1 | JA | null | null | null
> G1 | JJ | null | null | null
> HH | OT | null | null | null
> JA | PT | null | null | null
> G1 | JA | PT   | null | null
> B  | G1 | JA   | PT   | null
> C1 | HH | OT   | null | null
> A  | C1 | HH   | OT   | null
> B  | G1 | JJ   | null | null
> B  | G1 | JA   | null | null
> B  | EF | JK   | null | null
> A  | C1 | IU   | null | null
> A  | C1 | HH   | null | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e0db43dfa402787bf08d74d1b684eabe)*

Comment: Hi Kendle, thank you,. but we don't know how many n.. , how we can find the number of n ?. because the n is unlimited in this structure.

Comment: oh.. I am using SQL Server...

Comment: Here there are not entries in n5 so we know that we have gone far enough. There must be a dynamic method but it's easy to add columns until we get an empty one. NB You must have the same number of columns in the 2 queries `union all`