# Query that selects the names of all employees and the names of their bosses

Tags: sql

I need to write a query that selects the names of all employees and the names of their bosses. If there is no boss for an employee, return NULL. Bosses are consider to be employees as well.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  bossId INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (bossId) REFERENCES employees(id)
  );
  
  INSERT INTO employees(id, bossId, name) VALUES(1, NULL, 'Fred');
  INSERT INTO employees(id, bossId, name) VALUES(2, 1, 'Jason');
  INSERT INTO employees(id, bossId, name) VALUES(3, 1, 'Mike');
```

Expected result:

| name | boss |
| --- | --- |
| Fred |  |
| Jason | Fred |
| Mike | Fred |

Comment: This looks like an assignment.  Have you tried writing any SQL code yet?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914472/cte-to-get-all-children-descendants-of-a-parent

Comment: No I havent :( I have no idea...

Comment: Do a self left join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need left join, if the employee doesn't have a boss then show null in output

```
select emp.name,empBoss.name
from employees  emp 
left join employees empBoss
on emp.bossId = empBoss.id
```

Comment: I thought Joins use only with two or more tables…

Comment: Oh, yes you can use join for one table. It's Join a table to itself and you need this for the same query like "Companies that are fellow citizens" over the company table.

Comment: Thanks again, now I finaly understand.