# Create query on single table that create sub levels

Tags: sql-server

I have been task to create a query on a table that actually has multiple level in it.

The way the table is organize is as follows. I have the following columns

```
SYSID, NODE_TYPE, PARENT, ISFIRST, NEXT, DOCNO
```

- `SYSID` is a unique Identifier for each row.
- `NODE_TYPE` is a value either `F` or `D`. `F` is for folder and `D` is for documents
- `PARENT` is the parent folder where documents are supposed to be stored.
- `ISFIRST` tell if this is the first value in the folder or not.
- `NEXT` is the `SYSID` of the next value in the folder.

I must write a query that will find the folder, find all the entries in the folder, find if a sub folder exists and all sub values in the sub folders that could exists bellow that folder.

Something as shown in the screenshot.

The process can be many levels down.

Does anyone would have any idea on how I can create this?

I tried to create a cursor but I was not successful as it only went down one extra level.

I was thinking about creating a while loop but I do not have anything that I can think on using to perform the look without causing an infinite loop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You will need to use a recursive cte to do this. Any other route is either going to be exceedingly slow to execute or will cause you to run into a million brick walls.

Comment: you forgot the screenshot

Comment: What have you researched so far? Many answers exist such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914472/cte-to-get-all-children-descendants-of-a-parent)

Comment: Don't show a screenshot, please show sample data and expected results *as text*

Answer (score 0):

This query does not answer the question in full because your question doesn't completely explain the desired results

You can use window function and Cte to solve the problem:

```
;WITH MyTest as
(
  SELECT P.SYSID, P.PARENT,p.NODE_TYPE,p.ISFIRST,p.DOCNO, CAST(P.SYSID AS VarChar(Max)) as Level
  FROM a P
  WHERE P.ISFIRST = 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT P1.SYSID, P1.PARENT,P1.NODE_TYPE,P1.ISFIRST,P1.DOCNO, CAST(P1.SYSID AS VarChar(Max)) + ', ' + M.Level
  FROM a P1  
  INNER JOIN MyTest M
  ON M.SYSID = P1.PARENT
 )
SELECT * From MyTest
order by SYSID
```

You can insert the basic data with the following statements:

```
create table a(
SYSID int,
NODE_TYPE varchar(100), 
PARENT int, 
ISFIRST bit, 
NEXT int, 
DOCNO int
)
insert into a
(            SYSID,NODE_TYPE,PARENT,ISFIRST,NEXT,DOCNO)
      select 1 as SYSID,'f' as NODE_TYPE     ,null as PARENT,1 as ISFIRST,2     as NEXT,null as DOCNO
union select 2 as SYSID,'f' as NODE_TYPE     ,1    as PARENT,0 as ISFIRST,3     as NEXT,null as DOCNO
union select 3 as SYSID,'D' as NODE_TYPE     ,2    as PARENT,0 as ISFIRST,3     as NEXT,null as DOCNO
union select 4 as SYSID,'D' as NODE_TYPE     ,1    as PARENT,0 as ISFIRST,5     as NEXT,null as DOCNO

union select 5 as SYSID,'f' as NODE_TYPE     ,null as PARENT,1 as ISFIRST,6     as NEXT,null as DOCNO
union select 6 as SYSID,'D' as NODE_TYPE     ,5    as PARENT,0 as ISFIRST,null     as NEXT,null as DOCNO
```

Comment: Sorry about not explaining correctly. The result I am looking for is to be able to retrieve all link from each of the folder and the content of each of the folders. For instance if I had one primary folder and 15 sub folder in that table that are all linked to that primary folder, I want to be able to display the folders with their content in sort of a tree fashion  so that I can list the folder and its content. I hope this is more clear. I will place an example screenshot of what I am reffering to her.

Comment: please show example data and  expected results as text in content that I can understand well

Comment: I would have a screenshot of what I am looking for with my data but sorry for the stupid question but how do you add a screenshot?

Comment: please send example as text because i want to copy

Comment: No needs! Using the provided explanation, I was able to make this work. Thank you very much for the information provided. I just learned something new today.