# Recursive get all childrens using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, linq

i want to show all the parentID as possible using linq for example:
 if i select "submodule_idparent = 6" return all 5 and return 1. Because, to show 6 i need 5 and 1.

```
  submodule_id, submodule_name, submodule_idparent

  1             Articles        null
  2             Suppliers       null
  3             Adjustment      1
  4             Presentations   1
  5             Categories      1
  6             Subcategories   5
  7             Corridors       1
  8             Cellars         1
  9             Purchases       2
```

I'm try some like that with the next code (MySQL)

```
SELECT DISTINCT(submodule_id) FROM users_privileges LEFT JOIN modules_options USING(moduleoption_id) WHERE users_privileges.user_id = 1
```

but is not recursive.

Thanks in advance (y).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recursive Hierarchy - Recursive Query using Linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974248/recursive-hierarchy-recursive-query-using-linq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query=GetAll(6);  

public IEnumerable<users_privileges> GetAll(int submodule_id)  
{  
    var query = from c in db.users_privileges 
           where c.submodule_id == submodule_id
           select c;  

    return  query.ToList().Concat(query.ToList().SelectMany(t => GetAll(t.submodule_idparent)));                
}
```

http://blog.csdn.net/q107770540/article/details/7708418

Comment: I know it is slowly, but just an advice :)