# list all tags in XML with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing

I am trying to read variety type of XML files and in each xml type, root name and all other tags may change. I need to list all the xml tags but I couldnt succeed to read.

this is one of xml types.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-9"?>
<ITEMS>
   <ITEM DBOP="INS" >
      <CARD_TYPE>11</CARD_TYPE>
      <CODE>MALZ1</CODE>
      <NAME>MALZ1</NAME>
   </ITEM>
 </ITEMS>
```

and there is another one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-9"?>
<CLCARDS>
   <CLCARD DBOP="INS" >
      <CARD_TYPE>11</CARD_TYPE>
      <CODE>CLCARD1</CODE>
      <NAME>CLCARD1</NAME>
   </CLCARD>
 </CLCARDS>
```

I tried the code below but it didnt list all

```
string xml = txtXml.Text;
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

txtResult.Text = xdoc.Root.Name.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
foreach (XElement element in xdoc.Elements())
    txtResult.Text += element.Name.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
```

it just listed the tags below for the first xml

```
items
items
```

I want to list it like below

```
items
  item
    card_type
    code
    name
```

how can I get such a result with LINQ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20975582/1806780 for hints on how to do this, though it isn't LINQ, but it is enumerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can get all elements using the `Descendants()` method:

```
foreach (var element in xdoc.Descendants())
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Name);
}
```

However, that won't do any indentation. If you want indentation as well, you could use something like:

```
public static int GetDepth(XElement element)
{
    return element.Ancestors().Count();
}
```

Then:

```
foreach (var element in xdoc.Descendants())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}",
        new string(' ', GetDepth(element)),
        element.Name);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jon Skeet, is there a way to list those node with all path like 'ITEMS.ITEM.CODE' ?

Comment: @ARIFYILMAZ: List what nodes? It's not clear what you mean. If you mean you want each line to contain effectively the hierarchy of how you get to that element, then yes, it's absolutely possible. I've just thought of a simpler way of implementing `GetDepth`, btw...

Comment: I need to get a child node print it out with full path like '//Root//Child//Child'. Does it make sense

Comment: @ARIFYILMAZ: Yes - I suggest you look at the `Ancestors` method, combined with `Reverse()` and `string.Join`. If that doesn't help you, it would be best to ask another question.