# CTE (Common Table Expression) in EFCore

Tags: sql-server, recursion, entity-framework-core, hierarchy, sql-cte

I have a table in my DB that stores the hierarchy of locations. It has 3 columns `(Id, Name, ParentId)`. I need to load some row base on a condition and all their parents up to the root. If it was in ADO I would use the following statement.

```sql
with Temp
as
(
    select * from Locations where Name like '%filter%'

    union all

    select Locations.* 
    from Temp join Locations on Temp.ParentId = Locations.Id
)
select * from Temp
```

I am using EFCore and with a few searches I have found [How does Entity Framework work with recursive hierarchies? Include() seems not to work with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308158)
, [How to do recursive load with Entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266473) and a bunch of others which they are all old.

All the solutions I found either hardcoded the depth of the hierarchy (using `Include`) or do the recursion in C#. All that set, my question is that what is the best solution to do so?

I can use `FromSqlRaw`  (Something like the following code) however I don't like writing queries manually in C#.

```
    var locations = DataContext.Locations
    .FromSqlRaw("MyQuery").ToList();
```

I am using `EFCore 3.1.7`

Comment: With Oracle you have depthfirst/breadth first - not sure if SQL Server has the same. So perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636420/a-real-recursion-with-cte/11637387#11637387

Comment: Thank you for your comment @JGFMK but this link is the answer for SQL, not the EFCore. I have already provided it in my question.

Comment: If you don't like embedding the raw query text you can always write a view, stored procedure or table-valued function to return the data, and access that. I have no direct experience with EF Core but I'd be surprised if it has any support for recursive queries.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert, 
As I am using code first I should write raw queries to create the SP or View. So, it is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 8):

CTEs are not supported in EF Core out-of-the-box, see [issue #26486](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26486). However, library [linq2db supports CTE](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/CTE.html) and it [can be connected to EF Core](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore).