# implementing a recursive linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

So let's say that I have a table with a relation with itself, for example

```
Table Page
-------------
IDPage 
description    
IDPage_FK <-- foreign key
```

Now this table it's mapped by entity framework like this

```
Class Page
-----------
int IDPage
string description
int IDPage_FK
Page Page1
IColletion<Page> Page2
```

What I want to archive if it's possible, it's created a linq expression to navigate on all the table an make an output like this in a string variable:

Assuming this values in the table

```
IDPage    Description    IDPage_FK

1         Example        null

2         Example2         1

3         Example3         2
```

This output on a string variable

```
string inheritance = (from P in Page Select....)
```

The output will be like this

```
Example > Example2 > Example3
```

It's possible? or Do I have to create a method to loop into each element an create the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, you can't do recursive Linq out to a database - you'll probably either have to write an iterative function or create a stored procedure to do it for you.

Similar question:

[How does Entity Framework work with recursive hierarchies? Include() seems not to work with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308158/how-does-entity-framework-work-with-recursive-hierarchies-include-seems-not-t)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the [nested set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) rather than the parent pointer for mapping hierarchical relationships in a database table?

(Granted this isn't an answer, but may guide you down a better road long term)

Answer (score 0):

If you add a root node property into your model, you can query two levels: root nodes, all their children by root node id.  Then you can recurse against the in-memory instances to produce your string.