# Entity Framework Core Load Parent Records

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, parent-child

I have the following entity:

```
public class User
{
   public int UserId { get; set;}
   public string UserName { get; set;};
   public int UserSupervisorId { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("UserSupervisorId"}
   public User UserSupervisor { get; set;};

}
```

When I load a given `User` I always want to load their `UserSupervisor` and continue recursively to the top loading each `UserSupervisor` at each level.

When use the `Include` method it will only load the immediate parent and no further.  The code I use for this is:

```
var user = dbContext.Users.Include(u.UserSupervisor).SingleAsync(u => u.UserId == userId);
```

I can add a `ThenInclude` which will go up one further level.

I thought that relationship fix up would cause the graph to be loaded, granted I'm going from child to parent.

Is there a mechanism to do this in EF out of the box?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Entity Framework work with recursive hierarchies? Include() seems not to work with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308158/how-does-entity-framework-work-with-recursive-hierarchies-include-seems-not-t)